# Prefered OS for server - Windows 2008 x64 or Linux CentOs, Fedora, Ubuntu

Tags: operating-system, hosting

I want to know which want do you prefer for a Dedicated server... Yeah in 2 months I'll get a dedicated server but I don't know which OS to choose.

I use exec command from PHP to run .exe files... (like image converter, video converter) but I'm sure I can find that for Linux too... I don't know Linux very well, but I use Windows every day so maybe it will be easier for me?

Help me choose, please!

Thanks!

Comment: What's the use case? May belong at ServerFault.

Comment: Sorry, Jeremy, this is a vote to close this question. StackOverflow is a Q&A site, and it appears your question is off topic. Perhaps try http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: besides the fact this does not have an answer (besides a torrent of opinions)

Comment: Sorry guys... :S... but Michael Goldshteyn just answer my question... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either Linux or Windows is a good choice. Ultimately, though, the choice should come down to you or your sys admins ability to support your choice. The old adage about the TCO being in support is a fact.

Most of the time/cost is spent supporting the hardware/software and that should be the focal point of whatever decision you make. Both OSes are more than capable of running a dedicated server. Choosing an OS that you or your staff has no experience with is a good recipe for disaster and frustration, especially in the short term.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, short, understandable, true... :) I'll choose Windows :)